# How to call function when state changes except first loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to call function when state data changes but not first loading.
This is my code.

```
const Page = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;

  const arrowDirection = (item) => {
    if (item.arrow === 1) {
      return "up";
    } else {
      return "down";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index} className={arrowDirection(item)}>
            {item.name}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

In here, props data changes automatically every few seconds.
So I want to change classname to up or down according to the status.
But when page loads, I don't want to call `arrowDirection` function so that the classname to be set as empty.
Eventually, I don't want to set classname for the first loaded data, but for the data from second changes.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to update data in props and for first render let's say have item.arrow === null case for empty class. But if it is not possible, you may use useEffect+useRef hooks:

```
const Page = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;
  const d = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    d.current = true
  }, []);

  const arrowDirection = (item) => {
    if (item.arrow === 1) {
      return "up";
    } else {
      return "down";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index} className={d.current ? arrowDirection(item) : ""}>
            {item.name}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```